# How to make in C# a ListView with custom content just like Android's ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is there a way in C# where you can design ListView items and use and adapter just like Android has?

I have a UI proposal for my project and it requires this kind of feature.

The look is like this: [Project GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz4U4.png)

The RED area indicates the ListView and it has these items which have custom layouts.

Here is the layout of the item: [Item Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADZy9.png)

So, every time that the program detects an object it will create an item to the ListView with the preview of the Object.

Comment: Check this one: http://elb.componentowl.com/better-listview

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. It's not easy but you can. You must set the OwnerDraw property to true. You can then handle the [DrawItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem.aspx) event and do your own implementation. Alternatively, use a control like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx).

In WPF that job would be much more easy :)